# CSS image overlay not working

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get a transparent black overlay to appear when hovering over images on this page:

I am not sure where I am going wrong though, as this does nothing.  I would like the overlay to have a bit of padding from the sides of the image, which would also continue when the site is resized.

```css
.photo-gallery div {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 1%;
  width: 31%;
  position: relative;
}
.photo-gallery div a {
  line-height: 0;
  display: block;
}
.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 200;
  width: 90%;
  height: 90%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  display: none;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}
.photo-gallery div a:hover .overlay {
  display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.photo-gallery a {position: relative}
.photo-gallery a:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    transition: background-color 0.4s;
}
.photo-gallery a:hover:after {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}
```

Comment: This works well.  How would I go about adding a % of padding around the overlay?

Comment: ididn't get you

Comment: make it live so that I can try nd let you know

Comment: It is live at this point.  I would like that overlay to not reach to the sides of the image.  Rather I would like there to be some margin / padding so it looks like the overlay is somewhat sitting "inside" the image.

Comment: instead of making top, left, right, bottom as 0's make it 10, 10, 10, 10 for that spacing

Comment: When I do that the overlay no longer appears.

Comment: its not 10, it is 10x boss

Comment: .photo-gallery a:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    transition: all 0.4s;
}
.photo-gallery a:hover:after {
    top: 10px;
    left: 10px;
    right: 10px;
    bottom: 10px;
}

Comment: thats add transition like zooming out

Comment: Now I'd like to add a magnify glass in the center on hover.  You can see what I've done so far...  any ideas on how to get it to work?

Comment: .photo-gallery a i {
    display: none;
}
.photo-gallery a:hover i {
    display: block;
    z-index: 1;
}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131096/discussion-between-manikanta-reddy-and-user1110562).

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution would be to set a black background and change the opacity of the image on hovering

```css
a {
  background:black;
  display:inline-block;
}
img:hover {
  opacity:0.5;
}
```

```html
<a href="#"><img src="http://www.samanthamakeup.tv/_img/_photo-gallery/gallery-02.jpg"/></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a black background to the 'a' element and then add opacity to image on hover.

Something like this:

```
.photo-gallery div a {
   background-color:black;
}

.photo-gallery div a img:hover{
   opacity:0.8;
}
```

Comment: Almost a dub of my answer

Answer (score 0):

In this case you could just apply a faux background to the `after` pseudo selector on hover as so. No styling to the image would be needed to accomplishes this, aside from the vertical alignment to it's container.

```css
a {
  display:inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

a:hover:after {
  content: "";
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.7);
}

a img {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">
  <img src="http://www.samanthamakeup.tv/_img/_photo-gallery/gallery-02.jpg"/>
</a>
```

Answer (score -1):

Solution for the same

```css
.section-3::after{
 content: '';
 position: absolute;
 left: 0;
 top: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 opacity: .7;
 background:black;
 z-index: 1;
}

.section-3{
 position: relative;
 z-index: 2;
 padding: 20px 20px;
}

h1{
position: relative;
 z-index: 2;
 color:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="section-3">
  <h1>Hello i am text !</h1>
</div>
```

Use this code to apply overlay.